# Fire method using javascript variable variables

Tags: javascript

There is like 5 questions already answered but all of them says only how to create, what I need is to access.
In PHP we have:

```
$foo = new Foo();
$bar = 'methodName';
$foo->{$bar}();
```

How can I do this in JavaScript without using plugins? Code below fires method 'bar' of object 'foo', but I need to fire method from 'foo' object which name is assigned to variable 'bar'.

```
var foo = new Foo(),
    bar = 'methodName';
foo.bar();
```

Comment: `foo[bar]()` should do it.  This has been asked too many times to count: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `foo[bar]();`

This looks up the member name held in var `bar` on object `foo`, and invokes it as a method.